# Create .json file out of .env credentials to authenticate Google Cloud on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I want to use authenticate the Google Cloud API. So far that's only possible through a .json file. My application is hosted on Heroku. Now I don't want to push that .json file in my GitHub repository.

I found a [buildpack](https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack.git) that actually works. However, I don't want to rely on external buildpacks and wonder if there is another solution.

My idea similar to the buildpack:

1. Defining `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` in .env with:

```
    {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "natural-language-254706",
      "private_key_id": "XXX",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "abc@natural-language-254706.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "12345",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/starting-account-5yzg5dipgu01%40natural-language-254706.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

2. Take GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS and write google-credentials.json file with Python <<< **here I need help**
3. Define `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=google-credentials.json`

I am not struggling with 2. How can I create a .json file out of the credentials in 1.

I will add this second step (2.) then as part of the release-tasks in Heroku `python manage.py create_json_for_google_credentials`

Comment: Why do you need Python for this? You could very well adapt the [script in the buildpack](https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile) you found and run it as a release task.

Comment: @frankie567 I thought about that solution as well. Is it possible to create that script and release task inside my Django application? I decided against it at first because I wanted it to keep it inside my Django application and not create an extra GitHub repository/buildpack

Comment: Heroku detects the "bin" folder like in the buildpack you have used. You need to create this folder in your project with a "compile" file in it. You should run the code in the "compile" step to have access to [ENV_DIR](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-compile) which is used in the script.

Comment: @Nepo Znat a interesting. So just to double-check. I create a bin folder in my project, then create a compile file in it. And in that file I add the code from the other buildpack?

Comment: Yes exactly. This should work.

Comment: Hmm it seems to ignore the compile file on built. I already have a post_compile file in the bin folder that's working with some other tasks (collectstatic etc.). Do I have to "tell" Heroku somehow that compile file exists?

Comment: Here a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/xPhtxA8
It should print `------> Generating google-credentials.json` before, shouldn't it?

Comment: Oh ok so I think I've read the docs for buildpacks. I think using hooks should work in this case. I would try to rename the file to pre_compile because this is the name of a hook heroku uses when building your release.